Mysterious WiFi network being broadcast from my PC
I have a laptop (Framework 16) running Windows 11 Education 23H2 (Build 22631.3737). Today, I noticed a secure WiFi network called "Direct-URLAPPYmsQA" where "LAPPY" is the name of my machine. I have no idea what is enabling this network or what I might do to disable it, or even what the implications of it existing are. I'm not even sure how I would go about connecting to it since it's encrypted and I don't have a key to my knowledge. I'm pretty sure it's not something I enabled, and I can't find any settings for enabling/disabling WiFi Direct on Win11. Any help is appreciated!

Provide the output of Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "Direct*" -IncludeHidden in an elevated PowerShell command prompt by editing your question and including the relevant information. You can also just disable Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter, which will remain disabled, until you enable it.
